# Visual Studio - CDbl to Double.TryParse when inputting to array

Tags: vb.net

I'm finishing up a project and needed some clarification on a particular issue I'm running into.

```
     Do While intCount < dblNumbers.Length AndAlso strInput <> String.Empty         
     dblNumbers(intCount) = CDbl(InputBox("Please enter number " & (intCount + 1) & "."))

     intCount += 1

     Loop
```

I'm running into issues changing that a to Double.TryParse for validating as opposed to the CDbl. Any of the ways I've entered it have caused the inputs to not store in the array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryParse` doesn't return the converted value.  It returns the validation result.  You get the converted value from the parameter.

```
Dim number As Double

If Double.TryParse(InputBox("Please enter number " & (intCount + 1) & "."), number) Then
    dblNumbers(intCount) = number
Else
    'Invalid input.
End If
```